# Node.js: for..of with pipeline not waiting for completion

Tags: javascript, node.js, pipeline, fs

i am using a for..of loop with pipeline, but the statements after the loop are executed even before the pipeline finish exection, this happens even if i add await to pipeline

here is my relevant code

```
   for(const m of metadata) {
    if(m.path) {
      let dir = `tmp/exports/${exportId}/csv_files_tranformed/${m.type}`;
      let fname = `${dir}/${m.sname}`;
      fs.mkdirSync(dir,{recursive: true}, (err) => {
        if(err) throw err;
      });
      tempm = m;
      await pipeline(
        fs.createReadStream(m.path),
        csv.parse({delimiter: '\t', columns: true}),
        csv.transform((input) => {
            return input;
        }),
        csv.stringify({header: true, delimiter: '\t'}),
        fs.createWriteStream(fname, {encoding: 'utf16le'}),
        (err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error('Pipeline failed.', err);
          } else {
            console.log('Pipeline succeeded.');
          }
        }
      )
    }
  }
```

How do i ensure that the pipeline is fully completed before moving to the next statements.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the `pipeline` function?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-stream-pipeline-method/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide where the `pipeline` function comes from. It might be a third party library or from node's `stream`

If it is the `stream.pipeline` than the return of it is a stream, so `await pipeline(...` will not wait since it is not a `Promise`. You can turn the stream into a `Promise` with util, [Reference](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_source_transforms_destination_callback)

```
const util = require('util');
const { pipeline } = require('stream');
const pipelinePromise = util.promisify(pipeline);

// ...
await pipelinePromise();
```

Comment: I have tried this but get error `stream.on is not a function`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction, once i removed the `(err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error('Pipeline failed.', err);
          } else {
            console.log('Pipeline succeeded.');
          }
        }` block from my code, it worked.